# Check that sum of left and right children values equal value of the parent in Binary Trees?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, binary-tree

I'm writing a method for a homework problem on binary trees.

Objective:
Given a binary tree, check if the tree satisfies the property that for each node, the sum of the values of its left and right children are equal to the node's value. If a node has only one child, then the node should have the same value as that child. Leaf nodes automatically satisfy the property.

I am getting an error that my code is not correct for all cases. For example if I have a tree

15
/   \
5       10

I am returning false when it should be true.

Here is my method so far, what am I doing wrong?

```
boolean BTchecksum(BinNode root) {
    if (root == null || root.left() == null && root.right() == null) {return true;}

    BinNode leftNode = root.left();
    BinNode rightNode = root.right();

    int sum = (int)(leftNode.element()) + (int)(leftNode.element());
    int value = (int)(root.element());

    return (sum == value) && BTchecksum(root.left()) && BTchecksum(root.right());

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You wrote sum as:
`leftNode.element()) + (int)(leftNode.element)));`

Should be this:
`leftNode.element()) + (int)(rightNode.element)));`

Comment: happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 1):

Revision (no NullPinterException)

```
public boolean BTchecksum(BinNode root)
{   
    if (root == null || root.left() == null && root.right() == null) {return true;}

    int sum = 0;
    if (root.left() != null){sum = sum + root.left().value();}
    if (root.right() != null){sum = sum + root.right().value();}

    return (sum == root.value()) && BTchecksum(root.left()) && BTchecksum(root.right());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're probably getting null pointer exceptions because you're referencing children that may be null. This may not be the most efficient solution, but it takes care of all the cases.

```
public boolean BTchecksum(BinNode root) {
    if (root == null || root.right()==null && root.left()==null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (root.right() == null) {
        return (root.left().value() == root.value()) 
            && BTchecksum(root.left());
    } else if (root.left() == null) {
        return (root.right().value() == root.value()) 
            && BTchecksum(root.right());
    } else {
        return (root.value() == root.left().value() + root.right().value()) 
            && BTchecksum(root.left()) && BTchecksum(root.right());
}
```